# Access button from other class

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I got a `XIB` file called `LoginViewController.xib`, I have created a button called `login`(I know not the best name for a button), and I wrote some code in my `LoginViewController.cs` to my login button, but how do I access the button in another class called `CirkelWithButtonsViewController.cs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backing properties for Outlets created in `XCode` `IB` are private. You can't change that.

But you can create a public proxy. If you create a `login` button in `.xib`, your `LoginViewController.designer.cs` file will look like this (this file is autogenerated, don't edit it!)

```cs
[Register ("LoginViewController")]
partial class LoginViewController
{
    [Outlet]
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton login { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

You can proxy this button in your `LoginViewController.cs`

```
partial class LoginViewController
{
    //...
    public UIButton Login {
        get { return login; }
        set { login = value; }
    }
    //..
}
```

That being said, if you have to do that, your application has probably some architecture issues. You could probably use a MVVM pattern...